# How to align a bar and a line chart in ggvis in a dual y-axes plot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, linechart, ggvis, multiple-axes

Using the following code:

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
mydf2 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
            Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width)) 

mydf2 %>% as.data.frame()  %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~ Species, y = ~ Sepal.Length ) %>%
  layer_bars(fillOpacity := 0.1 ) %>%
  add_axis("y", "ywidth", orient = "right", grid = FALSE) %>%
  layer_lines(prop("y", ~ Sepal.Width, scale = "ywidth")) %>%
  add_axis('x', title='the species', properties = axis_props(labels=list(fill='blank'))) %>%
  add_axis('x', 'myx2', orient='bottom', title='') %>%
  layer_lines(prop("x", ~ Species, scale = "myx2"), stroke := 'blank')
```

Output:

[image]

My issue is:

- Does anyone know of a way to align the bar and line charts on this dual y-axes plot? I would like the tick marks to be aligned on the x-axis for both charts.

**Edit**

I decided to edit this question and provide a better example that shows better the problem.

Comment: This example doesn't run for me. `Error: Unknown properties: size.`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 4 months and a bit of researching I found a way around this issue although it is kind of a hack:

```
mydf2 %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(Species2= as.numeric(Species)) %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~ Species2, y = ~ Sepal.Length ) %>%
  layer_bars(fillOpacity := 0.1, width = 0.9 ) %>%
  add_axis("y", "ywidth", orient = "right", grid = FALSE) %>%
  layer_lines(prop("y", ~ Sepal.Width, scale = "ywidth")) %>%
  add_axis('x', title='the species', properties = axis_props(labels=list(fill='blank'))) %>%
  add_axis('x', 'myx2', orient='bottom', title='', grid=F) %>%
  layer_lines(prop("x", ~ Species, scale = "myx2"), stroke := 'blank')
```

**Output**

[image]

The rational behind the above answer is that in order for the line and the bar chart to be aligned the x-axis needs to be numeric. So, I made a new categorical x-axis which is used to plot an invisible line (check last two lines of code). The result is not optimal but it works.

You could also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485588/ggvis-layer-bars-and-layer-lines-on-different-y-axis/28490223#28490223) answer too.

P.S. The example code for the question comes from [this](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/366) post on github. The above has (luckily) been raised as an issue there. If it gets fixed (or there is a way to fix this) I will update the answer.